# Azure DevOps DACPAC deployment fails due to data classification statements

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines

I have classified some columns in my Azure SQL Database with Data Classification sensitivity labels. In the SSDT project that corresponds to the database, SQL statements like the following are present:

```
ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO
    [dbo].[tablename].[UserName]
    WITH (LABEL = 'Confidential', LABEL_ID = 'guid1'
        , INFORMATION_TYPE = 'Credentials', INFORMATION_TYPE_ID = 'guid2');
```

The SSDT project builds fine in VS 2019 as well as in the Build task in Azure DevOps Build Pipelines. As expected, I had to use a VS 2019 (hosted) agent because prior versions of SSDT don't recognize that SQL syntax.

In the pipeline, the DACPAC for that project is successfully built. I am then trying to deploy that DACPAC using an Azure SQL Database deployment task. It uses the SqlPackage.exe version it finds in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\ on the hosted agent. It apparently doesn't recognize those SQL statements and fails with the following error:

> The Element or Annotation class SqlSimpleColumn does not contain the Property class SensitivityLabel.

Is there a way to deploy a more updated SqlPackage.exe to a hosted build agent, or am I stuck waiting for Microsoft to update the image? Is there a way to pass a parameter to SqlPackage.exe instructing it to ignore those statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to deploy a more updated SqlPackage.exe to a hosted
>   build agent, or am I stuck waiting for Microsoft to update the image?

Afraid to say that, No, until now, we didn't offer the method for users to install the latest version of `SqlPackage.exe` into the image of hosted agent externally during its runtime, even if a temporary operation.

The `Sensitivity` labels has been added into a Azure SQL database, and also we has raised the PR internally to update the latest SQL Package.exe in hosted image: [Add support for latest SQL Package.exe and in MSBuild](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/issues/1206). I'm sure it will be deployed and updated soon.

> Is there a way to pass a parameter to SqlPackage.exe instructing it to
>   ignore those statements?

As I know, there isn't such parameter exists can for SqlPackage.exe compiled. In this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017#command-line-syntax), we list all of the parameter that supported. You can refer to this for detaild. As until now, it doesn't work for the `Sensitivity classification` in release job, we recommend you released the project with removing the `Sensitivity classification` used temporarily. Or you can build a private agent, install the SqlPackage.exe in it. Then run SqlPackage.exe command from its locations on your local machine.

I will monitor this internal PR process, once the PR finished and the new images deployed, will update my answer here to let you and other SO users know.

Comment: Where can I download the SqlPackage.exe that supports these statements?